# How to modify shape (image, connectionShape etc) width height and position using Open xml sdk?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

We can get shape dimension using-

```
shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.X //gives the x position of top left corner//
shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Offset.Y //gives the y position of top left corner//

shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.X //gives the x size of the shape : the width
shape.ShapeProperties.Transform2D.Extents.Y //gives the y size of the shape : the height
```

Can we also set these values?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you give additional information in your question about the nature of the classes and properties you are showing.  I see that this is probably some type of serialization from powerpoint, but without more information I can't determine how to answer.

Comment: We are trying to remove all animations from a powerpoint and bring the presentation to its final state. So if a scaling effect is there, we will have to set the scale programatically.

Comment: What is generating the classes that you are using?

Comment: We are using Open Xml sdk in C#.

Comment: We want to splits an animated PowerPoint file into separate slides.

Comment: Something like this plugin -  http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~rimondin/downloads.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can change ShapeProperties and modify shape offset and dimensions.
Following code scales down a shape to 50%.

shapeProp = shape.ShapeProperties;

```
        Int64Value prevWidth = shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cx;
        Int64Value prevHeight = shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cy;

        shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cx = (shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cx * 50) / 100;
        shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cy = (shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cy * 50) / 100;
        shapeProp.Transform2D.Offset.X += (prevWidth - shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cx) / 2;
        shapeProp.Transform2D.Offset.Y += (prevHeight - shapeProp.Transform2D.Extents.Cy) / 2;
```